# How to Integrate Google Calendar API with React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, google-api-js-client, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) vanilla js example of google calendar api in a react js app. The vanilla JS example works just fine in my local machine. But am getting lot of troubles when implementing the same in react. Please check my code below:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    var CLIENT_ID = '992549188018-3prg54pp18je3e3qhgcttgl11491c4dm.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
    this.state = {
      showAuthButton: false,
      showSignOutButton: false
    };
    this.initClient = this.initClient.bind(this);
    this.updateSigninStatus = this.updateSigninStatus.bind(this);
  }
  handleAuthClick(){
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }
  handleSignoutClick(){
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  }
  handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }
  initClient(DISCOVERY_DOCS, CLIENT_ID, SCOPES) {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      console.log(window.gapi);
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }
  updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.setState({
        showAuthButton: false,
        showSignOutButton: true
      })
      //listUpcomingEvents();
      //insertNewEvent();
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showAuthButton: true,
        showSignOutButton: false
      })
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.handleClientLoad();
  }
  render(){
    let authButton = <button id="authorize-button" onClick={this.handleAuthClick.bind(this)}>Authorize</button>
    let signOutButton = <button id="signout-button" onClick={this.handleSignoutClick.bind(this)}>Sign Out</button>
    return(
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.showAuthButton ? authButton : null}
        {this.state.showSignOutButton ? signOutButton : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Am getting this error as of now:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSignedIn' of null

Please guide me to move further...

Comment: You defined `CLIENT_ID` etc as variables in constructor but trying to access it as `this.CLIENT_ID`

Comment: @marzelin I have updated the code now, still getting the same error!

Comment: Either move config vars outside the component so that is can be reached by  `initClient` method, or assign config data to `this` object and access it that way.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without having access to the whole app. Could you upload your code to github so that I could clone it and reproduce the error?

Comment: Yeah, please check the [repo here](https://github.com/sivadass/react-meeting-room). I have configured the url: *localhost:8007* on Google API Console. Load it with any simple http server, am using python SimpleHTTPServer.

Answer (score 5):

Finally adding my solution which worked to help future comers :)

To get the list of events, authorization is not required. So removed the unnecessary code from google's quickstart example.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getEvents();
}

getEvents(){
  let that = this;
  function start() {
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': GOOGLE_API_KEY
    }).then(function() {
      return gapi.client.request({
        'path': `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${CALENDAR_ID}/events`,
      })
    }).then( (response) => {
      let events = response.result.items
      that.setState({
        events
      }, ()=>{
        console.log(that.state.events);
      })
    }, function(reason) {
      console.log(reason);
    });
  }
  gapi.load('client', start)
}
```

You can find the full code and functional demo [here](https://github.com/sivadass/react-meeting-room).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a HOC to load the google API:

```
import React from "react";
import { API_KEY } from "./constants";
import LoadingIndicator from "./common/LoadingIndicator";

export default function withGoogleApps(WrappedComponent) {
  class ComponentWithGoogleAPI extends React.Component {
    state = { gapiReady: false };

    componentDidMount() {
      this.loadGoogleAPI();
    }

    loadGoogleAPI() {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/client.js";

      script.onload = () => {
        window.gapi.load("client", () => {
          window.gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
          window.gapi.client.load("calendar", "v3", () => {
            this.setState({ gapiReady: true });
          });
        });
      };

      document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    render() {
      const { gapiReady } = this.state;
      if (gapiReady) return <WrappedComponent />;
      return <LoadingIndicator />;
    }
  }
  return ComponentWithGoogleAPI;
}
```

The you call it like this:

```
import withGoogleApps from "./withGoogleApps";

const AppConGoogle = withGoogleApps(App);
```

Then you can call gogle API's like calendar, for example:

```
const event = this.buildEventoGoogle(values);

const request = window.gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: "primary",
      resource: event
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You moved gapi config variables outside of the component, but didn't remove them from `initClient` parameters so they couldn't be accessed.
Here's proper code:

```
var CLIENT_ID = '992549188018-3prg54pp18je3e3qhgcttgl11491c4dm.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showAuthButton: false,
      showSignOutButton: false
    };
    this.initClient = this.initClient.bind(this);
    this.updateSigninStatus = this.updateSigninStatus.bind(this);
  }
  handleAuthClick(){
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
  }
  handleSignoutClick(){
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
  }
  handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', this.initClient);
  }
  initClient(/****here you've had parameters that made config vars unaccessible*****/) {
    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      console.log(window.gapi);
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.

      // ************* to access instance method you have to use `this.updateSigninStatus`  
  window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(this.updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

      // **************this code is unnecessary and causes errors***** 
      // authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      // signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    });
  }
  updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    if (isSignedIn) {
      this.setState({
        showAuthButton: false,
        showSignOutButton: true
      })
      //listUpcomingEvents();
      //insertNewEvent();
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showAuthButton: true,
        showSignOutButton: false
      })
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.handleClientLoad();
  }
  render(){
    let authButton = <button id="authorize-button" onClick={this.handleAuthClick.bind(this)}>Authorize</button>
    let signOutButton = <button id="signout-button" onClick={this.handleSignoutClick.bind(this)}>Sign Out</button>
    return(
      <div className="container">
        {this.state.showAuthButton ? authButton : null}
        {this.state.showSignOutButton ? signOutButton : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: I couldn't get where am making mistake, thanks for your help and time anyway :)